# How can Emacs-Lisp mode keep the echoed message when moving cursor around?

Tags: emacs, echo

- I notice that when using the Emacs-Lisp mode, if I place the keyboard cursor under an entity and move the cursor around that entity, then the message displayed in the echo area will not be cleared.

  For example, in the attached picture, if I move the cursor around the macro `evil-save-goal-column`, then the echoed message `defmacro: (NAME ARGLIST ...` is still there.

  [image]
- However, in almost other cases of the echo area, the message will be immediately cleared when the cursor changes its position.

  For example, in the below picture, the echo area displayed the message of `flycheck-mode`. If I move the cursor around the text `inasdfaf`, then the echo area is first cleared, then it is reloaded.

  [image]
- So, I wonder how the Emacs-Lisp mode make the echo area so special? How can it keep the echo area being uncleared when the cursor changes it position around a certain block of text? Can other mode do the same thing, e.g. the flycheck-mode or flyspell-mode?

Thank you very much for taking a look at my long post.

Comment: That is the default behaviour of `eldoc-mode`. As far as I know, if any buffer has `eldoc-mode` support, that's how it is going to work. 
You can always disable `eldoc-mode` if you want by adding a hook to `emacs-lisp-mode-hook`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I am looking for. Btw, do you want to create an answer instead of the comment so that I can upvote and accept it?

Comment: you might want to post questions regarding emacs under emacs stackexchange rather than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the functionality provided by `eldoc-mode`. For any major mode which has `eldoc-mode` support, if your cursor is positioned at a function(or even a variable), `eldoc-mode` will show the function name + the arguments it takes in the `mini-buffer` (note: `eldoc-mode` is enabled by default in emacs 25).

You can always disable it by pressing `M-x eldoc-mode RET` or, you can add a hook to your desired major-mode to have it disabled.